# Trouble using a IF condition and comparing values between two different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, csv

So I have a number of CSV file that contain a month worth of hourly data. I want to write a VBA code that retrieves each CSV file and writes a daily total to a newly created workbook. In this new workbook, each CSV file will have it's own sheet, and in the new sheet the hourly data will be converted to daily totals.

My code so far does all of the above, except for the proper calculation. I get the daily total by adding that hour's value to a blank variable for each row if that particular hour belongs in the day in question. (eg - the value for 1/12/2016 11:00 will be added to the destination column corresponding to 1/12:2016).

However, my source sheet is a CSV file in a folder, and my destination is a excel file newly created. My code does everything right, except for the calculation. My logic is accurate. So possibly the problem is that I'm not carrying my values through correctly.

```
Do While k <= how_many_cols         ' Each column in the data set
    destisheet.Cells(1, k).Value = sourcesheet.Cells(1, k).Value ' Column titles
    n = 2
    Do While n - 1 < m             ' n - 1 to get the last entry // Each row in the result set eg 1st = 31st
        x = 0       ' reset the totaliser
        j = 2       ' reset the row counter
        Do While j <= col_length
                '------
                ' Check date and totalise daily data amounts. Takes into account daylight savings
                If (sourcesheet.Cells(j, 1).Value >= destisheet.Cells(n, 1).Value + dls) And _
                  (sourcesheet.Cells(j, 1).Value < destisheet.Cells(n + 1, 1).Value + dls) Then

                Debug.Print sourcesheet.Cells(j, k).Address
                    x = x + sourcesheet.Cells(j, k).Value
                Debug.Print " x = " & x
                End If
                j = j + 1
                '------
        Loop
        destisheet.Cells(n, k).Value = x     'write to sheet
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    k = k + 1
 Loop
```

I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me what im doing wrong here. this is only a small extract of the code, but i think it's the relevant bit. I have defined everything at the start.

So this doesnt throw any errors. Except the value of x is always just zero, so it writes zeros to the destination sheet. to reiterate, the source sheet is an CSV file. Destination sheet is a seperate file.

More confusingly, as seen in the code, it imports the headings just fine. the data also corresponds with what I'm trying to import, so it should make the connections, which its not.

I am very new to VBA, so please excuse my coding. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the point of `Debug.Print " x = " & x`, does that print `0` as well?

Comment: What is `col_length`?  Where is it set?  Is your code actually executing those `Debug.Print` statements?  Add a `Debug.Print sourcesheet.Cells(j, k).Value` and make sure it isn't showing `0`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. The entire code is a bit longer than that. I just added the relevant bit. `col_length` is the number of rows in the source file, and it is calculated prior to the loops. I checked that value, and it returns the proper value. So its used to basically send the loop through each row of the source file, looking for that particular date, in that particular column.

Comment: I did added that bit of code to check the value of x. Its not zero. the value of x goes up. However, the value it prints to the destination sheet is still zero for some reason.

Comment: So going from where you suggested, I actually figured out what the problem is. The source sheet returns the date in the mm/dd/yyyy format, while the destination sheet has it in the dd/mm/yyyy format. So it doesnt even actually go past the IF statement. Ive been trying to change the format, but I need to do it in the VBA code itself, since the CSV files are generated by the system. Any idea how I can do that?